# IDispatchMessageInspector and Thread.CurrentPrincipal

Tags: wcf

I have implemented a custom IDispatchMessageInspector, in order to parse one custom token type. After parsing the token I assign:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext.Properties["ClaimsPrincipal"] = claimsPrincipal;

ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Identities"] = identities;
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;
```

I thought after ClaimsPrincipal got assigned in my IDispatchMessageInspector, It should have been available in my service method, unfortunately I've got a WindowsPrincipal(IsAuthentificated = false) there.

```
var currentIdentity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
```

any thoughts?

**Edit:**
My web.config:

```
<services>
      <service name="EchoService.TestEchoService">
        <endpoint address="api" bindingConfiguration="secured" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="rest" contract="EchoService.IEchoService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>        
        <behavior>
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">                        
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>        
        <behavior name="rest">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>        
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="echo.svc" factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" service="EchoService.TestEchoService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <clear/>
      <add type="EchoService.Host.Tokens.SimpleWebTokenHandler,EchoService.Host"></add>
    </securityTokenHandlers>    
  <audienceUris>
    <clear/>
    <add value="http://securitytestrealm/"/>
  </audienceUris>
          <issuerTokenResolver type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeyIssuerTokenResolver,System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt">        
            <securityKey symmetricKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=" name="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" />
          </issuerTokenResolver>
  </identityConfiguration>
```

**Edit2:**

Call sequence:

Contructor => GetTokenTypeIdentifiers => TokenType

In GetTokenTypeIdentifiers I return:

```
return new string[] { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2009/11/identitymodel/tokens/swt" };
```

This sequence takes only place if I call my service first time.
The interesting thing that none of Handlers methods are being called when it is called after that.

Answer (score 1):

Tokens should not be handled in IDispatchMessageInspector.

You need to implement SecurityTokenHandler that will allow you to read Token and extract whatever it carries => convert it to collection of claims and then return that collection. Provided claims collection will automatically be used to create ClaimsPrincipal by the WCF pipeline.

Check the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandler.validatetoken.aspx

**EDIT:**

You have two possible approaches to add token handler to pipeline. One is to implement custom service host:

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    protected override void OnOpening()
    {
        base.OnOpening();
        IdentityConfiguration identityConfiguration = new IdentityConfiguration();
        identityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.Clear();
        identityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(new CustomSecurityTokenHandler());
    }
}
```

or via same xml segments in web.config:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568671.aspx

**EDIT:**

```
        ServiceCredentials credentials = this.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>();
        if (credentials == null)
        {
            credentials = new ServiceCredentials();
            this.Description.Behaviors.Add(credentials);
        }
        credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried this approach. More over I've already implemented handler and token. The thing is that Token handler is not called by WIF/WCF pipeline and the quesion is why it would be called? WIF pipeline has no idea about my token and where it is stored in http message.

Comment: Check my edit. I've provided you with code on how to plug in handler into WCF pipeline.

Comment: Thanks again. I did this already... no luck. Security token is not called. If you have some time to review, I described the problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377021/when-custom-securitytokenhandler-gets-triggered

Comment: <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" /> Do you still have this line? This has to be set to Always.

Comment: Check my latest edit, I've added something else you might be missing (append to OnOpening in your CustomServiceHost).

Comment: Just tried. Now CustomsecurityToken Constructor is called and also GetTokenTypeIdentifiers method is called. Looks better but the methods CarReadToken and ReadToken are not called at all. I updated my first post, there is a web.config sections I have. Could you please review them? thanks.

Comment: You're supposed to override ValidateToken method and place your logic in there. Is that being called?

Comment: This method is overriden. ValidateToken method should be called after CanReadToken and ReadToken methods are called.  Please see my edits in the first post.Could it be that I return wrong token types that are supported by my TokenHandler?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this thing out.
The only thing that was missing is one setting in web.config.

```
<serviceBehaviors>        
<behavior>
<serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" />
```

Now it works as expected. Is there any security flaws?

Comment: Isn't it principlePermissionMode equals Custom rather than None.

Comment: There's no security problem here, but the recomended way to do it is via customs security token handlers, as in Barisa Puters answer.

Comment: The thing is that I have already implemented Handler and Token according to WIF documentation. If I just add the handler to the web.config file. It is just not being called by WIF pipeline. This is why I implemented a IDispatchMessageInspector.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, that's not how authentication in WCF works. You cannot simply assign Thread.CurrentPricipal from somewhere in the WCF processing pipeline and assume that WCF will automagically pickup that as a fact proving the user is authenticated.

You will need to hook into the right place of the pipeline. Which would be a [serviceCredentials behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx).

Comment: I already realized that I am somewhere in the middle of WCF stack and CurrentPrincipal was overridden just before the service call. the question is where is the right place in WCF stack?

Comment: There's a link in my answer. For custom authentication using username/password you would subclass UsernamePasswordValidator. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.aspx

Comment: How UsernamePasswordValidator can help me to pass ClaimsPrincipal that I've got in my IDispatchMessageInspector the in the service method?

Comment: I explain the idea: WCF recieves a token in IDispatchMessageInspector, then I transform the token into a ClaimsPrincipal. Then I have to assign somehow this ClaimsPrincial to the Thread.CurrentPrincipal for later use.