# When custom SecurityTokenHandler gets triggered?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wif

I have a simple REST Web Service. I have tried to implement SimpleWebToken security therefor I created a custom SecurityTokenHandler with overridden CanreadToken and ReadToken then I registered it in web.cofig file.

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <clear/>
      <add type="TestTokens.SimpleWebTokenHandler, TestTokens"></add>
    </securityTokenHandlers>    
 <audienceUris>
    <clear/>
    <add value="http://mytestrealm/"/>
 </audienceUris>
</identityConfiguration>
```

I thought that CanReadToken() is always called, in order to make sure that the incoming request can be handled.
Why it is not called?

Answer (score 0):

IFAIK, this collection of security handlers is only called when the WIF plumbing needs it.  This can be p.e. when you offer a WS-Trust service.  It is not called on all requests.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, WIF plumbing can be used to authenticate users. It looks like you are looking for more of a WebAPI solution.  I would recommend using Jwt tokens as everyone seems to be leaning that way. Have a look here: 
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/06/06/the-json-web-token-handler-for-net-4-5-reaches-ga/

We put in some features that help when validating jwt's for WebAPI's.